# How to get indicator's levels?

Tags: mql5

Is there any way for an expert advisor to get RSI indicator's levels, when the indicator was created/dropped by the user via MetaTrader's GUI?

To clarify, I have a handle in the indicator, I can query properties of the indicator with `IndicatorParameters`, but still can't get its levels.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood, you have an indicator that has levels ( e.g., 30 and 70 ) and want to get those levels. In such case - bad news is that you cannot get those levels, only set them, using these functions:

```
 IndicatorSetDouble(INDICATOR_LEVELVALUE,0,30);
 IndicatorSetDouble(INDICATOR_MINIMUM,0); 
 IndicatorSetDouble(INDICATOR_MAXIMUM,100);
```

but there's no function like `IndicatorGetDouble()`, so I am afraid you cannot receive such information